# jQuery toggle elements with class in parent div only

Tags: php, jquery, web-applications, toggle

I've been beating my head against my desk for the last two days over this one. I'm making an app that displays info from a db, the title/link, thumbnail, and time saved wrapped in an unordered list, like so: http://blog.madebycraig.com/images/full.jpg
What I'm trying to do is have a minimize button on the element, toggling the thumbnail and time saved on and off: http://blog.madebycraig.com/images/minimized.jpg
 I can accomplish this, but it's all or nothing. I click one minimize button, and everything goes. How can I contain it to just toggle items with a certain class name that are children of the div that the minimize button is in? I've tried .parent(), .child(), .next(), .prev(). I've thrown everything at it that I know. Now I turn to you, kind sirs (or madams). What am I doing wrong? Here's the ul I'm trying to run it on.

```
echo'
<li class="bookmarkContainer">
<a href="'.$row['url'].'" class="toggle"><img class="thumb" src="images/placeholder.png" /></a>
<div class="title"><a href="'.$row['url'].'" class="bookmrk" target="_blank">'.$row['title'].'</a></div>
<div class="dt toggle">'.relativeTime($row['dt']).'</div><br />
<a class="collapse" href="#">hide</a>
<a class="delete" href="?delete='.$row['id'].'" id="'.$row['id'].'">Delete Bookmark</a>
</li>';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) like this:

```
$(".collapse").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.bookmarkContainer').find('.toggle').toggle();
});
```

If you have lots of these, or they are changing via ajax (seems like a search-resulty thing), use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) like this:

```
$(".collapse").live('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.bookmarkContainer').find('.toggle').toggle();
});
//or...
$("#ulID").delegate('.collapse', 'click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.bookmarkContainer').find('.toggle').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much. That just goes to show why I'm a web designer and not a web developer!